# Can't install Ruby on mac via RVM, process is awk

Tags: ruby, rvm

Decided to install the latest Ruby 1.9.3. But after running the command, process freezes.

Here is a log:

```
admin$ sudo rvm install 1.9.3
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p448.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on       binary rubies.
Installing requirements for osx, might require sudo password.
DEBUG: Copying /Users/admin/Library/Preferences/com.apple.dt.Xcode.plist to   /opt/local/var/macports/home/Library/Preferences
DEBUG: MacPorts sources location: /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs
--->  Updating MacPorts base sources using rsync
receiving file list ... done
base.tar

sent 13372 bytes  received 9123 bytes  2367.89 bytes/sec
total size is 4915200  speedup is 218.50
receiving file list ... done
base.tar.rmd160

sent 64 bytes  received 635 bytes  199.71 bytes/sec
total size is 512  speedup is 0.73
DEBUG: successful verification with key /opt/local/share/macports/macports-pubkey.pem
DEBUG: /usr/bin/tar -C     /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/tmp -xf   /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/base.tar
MacPorts base version 2.1.3 installed,
DEBUG: Rebuilding and reinstalling MacPorts if needed
MacPorts base version 2.1.3 downloaded.
--->  Updating the ports tree
Synchronizing local ports tree from rsync://rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports.tar
DEBUG: /usr/bin/rsync -rtzv --delete-after      rsync://rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports.tar  /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs
receiving file list ... done
ports.tar

sent 51172 bytes  received 1631 bytes  8123.54 bytes/sec
total size is 53268480  speedup is 1008.82
DEBUG: /usr/bin/rsync -rtzv --delete-after       rsync://rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports.tar.rmd160      /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs
receiving file list ... done
ports.tar.rmd160

sent 64 bytes  received 636 bytes  107.69 bytes/sec
total size is 512  speedup is 0.73
DEBUG: successful verification with key /opt/local/share/macports/macports-pubkey.pem
DEBUG: /usr/bin/tar -C  /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/tmp -xf /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports.tar
Creating port index in    /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/release/tarballs/ports
Adding port science/openbabel

Total number of ports parsed:   1 
Ports successfully parsed:  1 
Ports failed:           0 
Up-to-date ports skipped:   17387

--->  MacPorts base is already the latest version
DEBUG: Setting MacPorts sources ownership to root

The ports tree has been updated. To upgrade your installed ports, you should run
port upgrade outdated
Installing required packages: apple-gcc42, libyaml, readline, libksba, curl-ca-bundle.....
```

After this nothing else happens.

I installed this packages via HomeBrew but after running rvm nothing changed.

Comment: Is "awk" a new word for "frozen"? I'm guessing MacPorts is just busy compiling those packages. apple-gcc42 should take a long time to compile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved that problem. I just removed MacPorts =) And all packages were recognized as already installed via Homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be you confused rvm by calling it with `sudo` - you should not do that unless explicitly asked for it (like in an error message: run "sudo ..." to fix something), the same applies to `rvmsudo`, use it only when it is explicitly requested.

RVM will show the password prompt for `sudo` when it is needed and will escalate privileges only for the command that requires it - usually it is interacting with package manager.